# Entity Framework Add-Migration command generates schema changes in the wrong order

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm, entity-framework-6

When creating an Entity Framework migration, some of my schema changes are being generated in the wrong order. This happens when adding columns to an existing entity that only has a single primary key index (more on this later). For example:

```
namespace MyApp.Migrations
{
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class MyMigration : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "MyTableName",
                c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    // ... rest of columns
                })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

            DropTable("MyTableName");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "MyTableName",
                c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    // ... previous column state
                })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

            DropTable("MyTableName");
        }
    }
}
```

Other column changes appropriately use `AddColumn()` and `DropColumn()` respectively. For those tables whose columns are updated and use the aforementioned methods, they have existing foreign key indexes, unlike the tables I'm currently having issues with.

It's one thing for EF to just drop and recreate the tables which I don't mind much in itself. I just shouldn't have to go into a migration file and manually change the order of the operations myself. I feel that EF should be intelligent enough to know that it should drop first then create.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you show how you are doing the map of the entities??

Comment: For the entities that are behaving correctly, I'm simply leveraging EF conventions, i.e. `ICollection<ForeignEntity> MyForeignEntities { get; set; }` or `ForeignEntity MyForeignEntity { get; set; }`. The others do not contain any foreign keys. In the `OnModelCreating()` method in the context class, I'm not doing anything out of place, just mapping to unconventional table names and mapping non-natively supported columns such as the XML type. I should mention that I had neglected to include one entity as a `DbSet<T>` property in the context before generating the migration.

Comment: As my understating, it won`t have any problems to you on that situation. Because, if you only have a table, that contains the id itself, if you add another column on that, the entity framework will have that behavior. As far as I remember, its the default behavior of EF do that.

Comment: What I didnt understand its, why you are creating the entities with only ID? Is that something especific??

Comment: There are more columns than what is displayed, I only indicated those via the comment for brevity. The main concern here is that EF is incorrectly generating migration code and I don't know why.